# How to implement two classes for automatic decision over deep and shallow copy?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I have the following design problem:
I have a `Resource` with two sorts of accessors:

- one is to modify it (let's call it `Access`)
- one is for const-like access (let's call it `Const_access`), but you could say c1=c2 and then c1 will access c2.

Given that `Resource` is big, I have to achieve the following copy mechanism:

```
Access->Access:             deep copy
Access->Const_access:       deep copy
Const_access->Access:       deep copy
Const_access->Const_access: shallow copy
```

I aim to write `Access` so that `Const_access` will be able to use exactly the `const` functions in `Access`.
My current implementation is flawed, using:

```
class Access {
  public:
  Access(const Access&); // deep copy
  void method(const Access&); 
  void const_method() const; 
  protected: 
  Resource res;
};
class Const_access : public Access{
  private:
  void method(); // only declaration
  public:
  Const_access(const Const_accesss&); // shallow copy
  explicit Const_access(const Access&); // deep copy
};
```

but here `Const_access ca; ca.Access::method()` still works and I have to manually hide away the non-const accessors. I have tried protected or private inheritance but that prohibits flexibility for `Access&` to handle `Const_Access&` too.

What would be the correct solution for this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I write different copyCtor for const and non-const instances?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343718/can-i-write-different-copyctor-for-const-and-non-const-instances)

Comment: Since the contract of  `Const_Access` is narrower than that of `Access`, the inheritance as stated makes no sense. A `Const_Access` cannot be used in place of an `Access`, so it would be a violation of the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate question because of the added kink of violating the Liskov substitution principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can simply solved using so called **lazy evaluation**:
making the private clone of the class resources only when a member function wants to modify it. R/W and Read-only access to resources is easily solved with private inheritance.

This way also the LSP is abided: `Obj` is now flawlessly publicly inherited from `Const_obj`, if necessary at all.
[There is a link for the complete answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13384120/1705967)

Answer (score 2):

What you are saying is contradictory.

On the one hand, you want to disallow things like:

```
Const_access foo;
foo.modify();
```

but on the other hand, you do want to allow things like:

```
void bar(Access& a) {
    a.modify();
}

Const_access foo;
bar(foo);
```

This does not make sense.

A more logical relationship is to turn the inheritence structure around:

```
class Const_access {
public:
    Const_access(const Const_access&); // shallow copy
    void const_method() const;
protected:
    Resource res; // or perhaps a reference-counted pointer?
};

class Access: public Const_access {
public:
    Access(const Access&); // deep copy
    explicit Access(const Const_access&); // deep copy
    void method();
};
```

The only thing it does not give is a deep-copy when converting an `Access`  to a `Const_access`.

Comment: Yes, this would be the normal solution but as you wrote it does not give deep copy on `Access` to `Const_access`. And this was my reason to come up with an upside-down nasty looking stuff in the question. :( So complicated :(

Answer (score 0):

Your function `method()` has public visibility in the base class but is private in the derived class. This violates the Liskov substitution principle. A derived class should extend rather than contract the base class.

The solution is to not violate that principle. For example, make the inheritance in `class Const_access` private or protected, or provide an implementation `method()` in `class Const_access`.